# rails activeadmin drop down menu on new and edit forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a has_many belongs_to association. I registered the resource. I have shipments that belong to customers.

But when I go to the new shipment form, in the drop down select menu for customers I get #<0X0000>

Why? How can I fix it?

I think it's because the Customers table doesn't have a "name" attribute, instead I have company_name. How can I use company_name in the drop down menu?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705372/ruby-on-rails-active-admin-has-many-changing-dropdown-to-use-a-different-column) for a more complete answer to your question.

Answer (score 17):

You **shouldn't override** to_s method, active admin can use display_name method specially for this case

so you can add next to your model

```
  def display_name
    company_name
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

One option is to override `to_s`

```
def to_s
   company_name
end
```

Other option is the following:

```
f.input :customer, :as => :select, :label_method => : company_name , :value_method => :id
```

Answer (score 4):

```
f.input :customer, :label_method => :company_name
```

Answer (score 0):

define a "to_s" method on your customer model. Something like this:

```
def to_s
  company_name
end
```