# Changing what attribute is displayed in drop down association filter in active admin with Rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using the Active Admin gem in my Rails app, and on one of my models admin page, there is a filter for an association to another model.  The drop down menu is displaying `#<Model:AxAAAAAA>` as opposed to the appropriate attribute.

For instance, if my model were posts, which belonged to users, on the posts admin index page, there would be a filter for users, and in the drop down menu for that filter would be id's such as `#<User:abcd12345>`.  I would like to be able to display something appropriate in the drop down menu for this filter.  How can I do this with Active Admin?

UPDATE

As pointed out in the answer by ciastek, this is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578819/rails-activeadmin-drop-down-menu-on-new-and-edit-forms) and in fact, I am also using "company_name" as an attribute instead of "name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by passing `:label_method => :company_name` to the resource in the resources.rb file under the 'admin' directory.

Answer (score 1):

Simmilar to [rails activeadmin drop down menu on new and edit forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8578819/257443), answer the same.

- Use **name** as a name of field which should represent instance.
- Define **to_s** method - value returned by this method will be used as representation.