# Ruby On Rails Active Admin has_many changing dropdown to use a different column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am completely new to ActiveAdmin and RoR and i cant figure out how to change the visible value of the dropdowns in a has_many association.

### Fillup Model

```
class Fillup < ActiveRecord::Base
    // key is car_id:integer
    belongs_to :car
end
```

### Car Model

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :description, :presence => true
    key is fillup_id:integer
    has_many :fillups
end
```

### What it currently shows:

It currently shows im assuming an encoded reference to the Car assigned to it.
[image]

### What i need it to show:

I need it to show the description given which is defined as `description:string` in the `Car Model`.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this should work...

In `app/admin/model_name.rb`

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "My Model Name" do
    # add your other inputs
    f.input :cars, :collection => Car.all.map{ |car| [car.description, car.id] }
    f.buttons
  end 
end
```

Read [this article](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html) to learn more about modifying the form.

AciveAdmin uses [formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), you should read about that as well.

Comment: where would i add this at? Again, im a bit of a RoR noob and using this as a stepping stool to get into RoR a bit more.

Comment: This still isnt working properly. You can view the full code here: https://github.com/gorelative/TestApp, direct link to where i put the code is: https://github.com/gorelative/TestApp/blob/develop/app/admin/fillups.rb

Comment: Replace `f.input :car_id...` with `f.input :car...` . ActiveAdmin understands relations.

Comment: That did it, learned a ton just by this simple question. Thanks for your hard work. I really appreciate it.

Comment: just in case you're wanting some more rep.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707308/ruby-on-rails-active-admin-has-many-changing-text-to-use-a-different-column

Answer (score 5):

In your `Car` model, just add something like :

```
def to_s
  description
end
```

It should do the job !

*Explanation :* Actually, your `Car`'s `to_s` method returns the object id corresponding to the current instance, that's the default thing used when using a method like puts on an object. To replace a model's display name, you have to override this method and it will work anywhere in your app when you use `puts @car` or in your templates doing `<%= @car %>`

Comment: I searched for this everywhere. For any CakePHP developer out there, this is similar to setting $displayField in your model.