# Ruby On Rails Active Admin has_many changing text to use a different column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

This is similar to my previous question [Ruby On Rails Active Admin has_many changing dropdown to use a different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705372/ruby-on-rails-active-admin-has-many-changing-dropdown-to-use-a-different-column/10705422#10705422)

I figured out how to reassign a `f.inputs` but how would i go about reassigning the display of  the data when viewing an item...

e.g:

[image]

Public Git Repo: https://github.com/gorelative/TestApp

Snippet of code i have in my `fillups.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Fillup do
    form do |f|
        f.inputs do
            f.input :car, :collection => Car.all.map{ |car| [car.description, car.id] }
            f.input :comment
            f.input :cost
            f.input :mileage
            f.input :gallons
            f.buttons
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: check out one of my [repos](https://github.com/kgann/wtl) for more ActiveAdmin examples... not saying they are perfect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `show` action

```
ActiveAdmin.register Fillup do
  # ... other stuff

  show do
    attributes_table do
      # add your other rows
      row :id
      row :car do |fillup|
        link_to fillup.car.description, admin_car_path(fillup.car)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Kyle, would you be available to answer a few more quick questions in regards to this?

Comment: I'm about to go to a meeting. Check my SO profile and gmail chat me and I will get back to you.