# Active Admin Output in Drop Down List Generated From Seeds.rb Not Correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, activeadmin, postgresql-9.2

My environment is like this:

```
Rails 3.2.13
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
postsql 9.2
```

I created the States table with this migration:

```
class CreateStates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :states do |t|
        t.string "states"
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def down
    drop_table :states
  end
end
```

I used this seeds.rb file to populate my states table:

```
State.delete_all
 open("/opt/nginx/html/blog/db/states.txt") do |states|
 states.read.each_line do |state|
 State.create!(:states => state)
end
```

In my rails console the output looks fine (except for the "/n")

```
> state = State.first
  State Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" LIMIT 1
  => #<State id: 225, states: "Alabama\n", created_at: "2013-07-11 03:51:43",
  updated_at: "2013-07-11 03:51:43">
```

Using an association, States is in the ActiveAdmin module for Conferences. But when rendered in the browser I get this:

```
<option value="225">#&lt;State:0x00000105a608f0&gt;</option>
```

I'm sure that the rake db:seed caused the problem. The "/n" is an indication.

Any and all help resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename the `states` column in the `states` table to `name` as it seems confusing. To get rid of trailing `\n` you can do

```
open("/opt/nginx/html/blog/db/states.txt") do |states|
  states.read.each_line do |state|
  State.create!(:states => state.chomp)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try tonight. But is it the trailing \n that is causing this output problem?

Comment: No. `\n` isn't required anyways. Another way to resolve this is to override `to_s` method in the model. As suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8603335/1087546) but you should change the name to avoid confusion and it will work without any override